# Template deduction guide fails with 'too many initializers' error

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, aggregate-initialization

I was reading on template deduction then tried to create one.
as follows:-

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
template<int i,typename A,typename... B> struct deducted{

};
//Deduction guide
template<typename A,typename... B> deducted(A a,B... b)->deducted<0,A,B...>;
//

int main(){
    deducted a={"","",""};
    deducted b={0,0,0};
    array c={0,0,0};
}
```

what supprises me is the test fails with `error: too many initializers for 'deducted<0, const char*, const char*, const char*>'` but the `std::array` version works fine. What could i be possibly missing, and can anyone rewrite much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many initializers because there's noting to receive what you initialize it with.

Example fix:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int i, typename A, typename... B>
struct deducted{
    A a;
    std::common_type_t<B...> arr[sizeof...(B)];
};
```

[Demo](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/eqG9Pe)

Answer (score 1):

Deduction works, but then, construction fails.

Provide constructor. (or appropriate members for aggregate initialization).

Comment: I don't see a constructor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/array). So i tried copy the same.

Comment: There is the aggregate initialization.